# Is there a way to return out of multiple functions?

Tags: c++

I have a problem that I think is a limitation of C++.

I'm making an input library, and I want to avoid using if statements in a function that will be called probably hundreds of times per second (for performance reasons)
and this is possible in x64 assembly code

I intend to make an array of function pointers and call those pointers without any ifs, and have a loop that just calls the pointers until it reaches the end without any conditions (so can't use `while(condition)` or `for(;conditon;)` or `if` or anything like that)
The way I would do it in assembly is always have a function at the end that adds the amount of data from the stack that the function running the loop allocated, and then returning to whatever is at the top of the stack, effectively returning out of the function from within the final function called from the array of function pointers.

The only way I can think of this is making said function purely in inline assembly, but then the size of the stack may vary from compiler to compiler and compiler version to compiler version, surely resulting in crashes when compiled.
I could pre-compile this into a DLL/elf module and link against it at runtime but I wanted to make my input library run fully off a .h file or .cpp file (because I think that's simpler and easier to work with, I make all my libraries as single source code files) So that's not ideal either.
Is there a way to return out of multiple functions at once?

Example code that works when compiled on mingw_w64 10.1.10:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void func2()
{
    cout << "we are here.";
    asm("add $0x58, %rsp");
    asm("ret");
    cout << "and not here.";
    return;
}

void func1()
{
    cout << "lol";
    func2();
    cout << "did I skip it?";
    return;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "starting...";
    func1();
    cout << "success?";
    return 0;
}
```

output: `starting...lolwe are here.success?`

Comment: There's always `setjmp`/`longjmp` ...

Comment: Avoiding `if` statements is an arbitrary requirement - and not guaranteed to give performance benefits like you assume. Your approach of hand-optimising performance using low level constructs without doing any testing/profiling to provide evidence of a need is called "premature optimisation" for a reason.   In any event, you can return control through an arbitrary depth of function calls by throwing an exception that is caught in `main()` or by using `setjmp()`/`longjmp()`. Performance depends on details of quality of implementation of the compiler but so does usage of assembler.

Comment: Running your assembler code with `-fsanitize=address,undefined` suggests that it's [not great](https://godbolt.org/z/abG7qK88e)

Comment: It is really dangerous to mix asm and C++ code like that. That can easily leads to undefined behavior and hard to find bugs. For example, if you have a local object, its destructor won't correctly be called. And also by using asm code you will probably prevent the compiler from optimizing (for example by making the function inline) and have worst performance that in pure C++. The above code would works only for a specific calling convention...

Comment: Are you certain that this optimization is even actually necessary? I wouldn't even consider something like this without extensive profiling to see if it is even a bottleneck  in your code. Odds are, it isn't.

Comment: Having said that, if you are determined to try this, I would suggest simply unrolling the loop manually, assuming that there is a fixed number of functions and the order is known at compile time. Otherwise, if you can ensure that the compiler supports tail-call optimization (which some C++ compilers allow as an option), you could us [continuation-passing style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style) to chain the functions, passing the results of each function to the next one. If the compiler doesn't support TCO, then use `setjmp()` and do CPS as before.

Comment: While CPS is usually a functional programming technique, it is applicable in general, *if* TCO is supported or some other method of unwinding the stack is available (though without TCO, you still have to deal with the stack growing throughout the sequence of functions). It is not uncommon to use CPS as a method for compiling FP languages to C code.

Comment: Whatever you do, profile the code both before and after the optimization is applied, and see if it actually has improved the performance in a measurable way. Again, experience tells me that it probably won't, and in fact will probably pessimize the code rather than optimize it.

Comment: Another vote for "this is probably a bad idea."  But if you must, make sure you check out the [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Basic-Asm.html#Basic-Asm): *Do not expect a sequence of asm statements to remain perfectly consecutive after compilation. If certain instructions need to remain consecutive in the output, put them in a single multi-instruction asm statement. Note that GCC’s optimizers can move asm statements relative to other code, including across jumps.*  So having two asm statements like that is not a good idea.

Comment: @Schol-R-LEA With CPS you really need a compiler with tail-call optimization. No function ever returns, everything is a tail call. If you don't have TCO you can use co-routines to make your own tail calls.